# Passing structs in Interprocess Communication in C

Tags: c, ipc

I have a C program which runs on windows and on ubuntu linux.
It creates two process running in parallel.

In have to establish inter process communication between the two process passing C structs(may be nested too) between them. The struct will be having some runtime parameter values.
Which IPC should I use?

If I use zmq then any serialization library to be used on C(no C++)?

Comment: C++ code can link to C code so I don't see "C only" as a requirement. On the C++ side, the structs must be `extern C`, to remain binary compatible, but you can handle them with any C++ code you want, and then link the C project with the C++ code that does serialization.The "C only" as a requirement only makes sense if there's some embedded platform that has no C++ support. Both Windows and Ubuntu handle C<->C++ interop with no issues.

Comment: Thank you Reinstate for the suggestion. But its a client code and the compiler is set to GCC which we cannot change.

Comment: GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection. The GNU Compiler Collection includes front ends for C, C++

Comment: GCC compiles C++ code, and moreover you'd be linking to a library that exposes a C API, even if the library itself is written in C++. In many cases C projects on linux already link to libraries written in C++ without you even knowing it, because it doesn't impose any additional requirements. The library is a black box - you don't get to see what it's written in.

Comment: _Which IPC should I use_ is a very broad question.   What problem are you having with `xmq` ?

Comment: Main objective is to pass structs between the process. So which ipc is good for this.

Comment: We had tried using protobuf but compiling our code using mingw64 gives error mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include/c++/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'. In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':

Comment: Do you need "-lstdc++" or something like that for MinGW? In any event, I don't think that error necessarily has anything to do with your choice of libraries. More broadly, choosing an IPC technology doesn't really turn on the need to pass structures -- that's a matter of serialization, not of IPC as such. Choice of IPC comes down to design requirements -- what sort of redundancy (if any) do you need? What sort of load sharing? Should the data in flight be persistent and, if so, where? Do you need point-to-point or distribution semantics, etc. None of this is related to serialization.

Answer (score 0):

[nanomsg](https://nanomsg.org/) and [nng](https://github.com/nanomsg/nng) (nanomsg-next-gen) are open-source alternatives to zmq for C. Also there are many bindings for other languages; like C++, ruby, java, go, python etc.

Comment: can we pass nested struct using it

Comment: if nested struct includes a pointer to another struct, no; otherwise yes.